# How to check if there exists a frame in which a given buffer is visible

Tags: buffers, frames

this question is related to the question 
[How to know my buffer's visible/focused status?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2959/).

I would like to check if there exists a frame in which a given buffer is visible.
I tried the following but it gives true even if `scratch` is invisible.

```
(get-buffer-window (find-buffer-visiting "*scratch*") 'visible)
```

Comment: This seems to work: `(get-buffer-window "*scratch*" 'visible)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear why you want the call to `find-buffer-visiting`.
The following works as expected:

```
(get-buffer-window "*scratch*" 'visible)
```

Comment: The first argument is supposed to be a buffer, so although it is permissive and accepts a buffer name instead, I recommend you write `(get-buffer-window (get-buffer "*scratch*") 'visible)`, to try and reduce the confusion between buffers and buffer names.